# Azure Application Gateway Redirection exclusion for specific IPs?

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

i'm wondering if it's possible to configure a redirection on the Application Gateway and exclude an IP range from it.

Let's say i have a website configured and i'm currently running a maintenance tasks. So i'll configure a redirection on the application to my maintenance site. But after the maintenance is finished i want to check first if everything is fine before removing the temporary redirection. So for example my IP should be able to access the "real" website and all other requests are still forwarded to the maintenance page. Is this maybe possible with the traffic manager?

I haven't found anything really helpful untill now. Has someone an idea how this might be possible to configure?

Answer (score 0):

Redirection based on specific IPs is not possible using the application gateway as far as I'm aware. But this feature is available with Azure APIM, and this is exactly the type of scenario were APIM is useful. You can set your Back-end service URL based on specific conditions (including IP filters). see link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-transformation-policies#SetBackendService

For a full list of APIM polices : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-policies